# Best way for reminder/alarms

Tags: java, android

After many researches I'm stuck with the problem:

Setting up one alarm by user for my app with setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is limited to one trigger per 9 minutes.

Which leads to another problem, as my alarm is repeating. My broadcast receiver is setting new alarm, but if I have 2 alarms, one 4:00 and the second one 4:05, its getting bugged, triggers those alarms with few minutes delay or triggers them 2 times instead of once.

It is bugging after device goes into doze mode.

Are there any alternatives to bypass that problem?
Other way for reminder feature?

I have tested my app on Android 7.0

Answer (score 0):

i think u may use sqllite and create table called timeTabel to store alarm time and then u will be able to manage it one by one

Comment: Still, i would be using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, which in fact fails in doze mode if you have alarms too often

Answer (score 0):

Try the native Android clock approach:

1. Use any storage to save and manage your Alarms, e.g. preferences or any kind of ContentProvider - doesn't matter
2. Schedule your alarm not to the exact time, schedule it to 30-60 minutes before the actual time
3. When alarm is triggered, do not play it. Just start your foreground service, which will put the foreground notification to the system tray (to remind user about the alarm), such service will not be affected by doze mode and will keep CPU up
   3.1. Schedule alarm to the exact time you need.
   3.2. In theory, foreground notificaiton will not let your device to switch to doze mode, so you can handle such alarams easily
   3.3. For new API, you can find here pretty good blog [**post**](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo?linkId=17112180) 
   Which will allow you to use:

`On API 21+ devices, new APIs allow you to set a user visible alarm via setAlarmClock();`

[Documentation for setAlarmClock()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

4. When alarm is triggered - update your notification with Stop alarm button, play sound, anything you like
5. When alarm is completed (stopped or by timeout), manage its state and manage next alarms state, if repeat period is very short - use `Handler` to repeat, if long - reschedule using described logic.

Perhaps `setAlaramClock();` will do all the magic, but foreground notification + service should be good solution as well.

Happy coding! (=